# How to convert JavaObject from POJO to JSONString/JSONObject

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

I have a POJO which returns JAVAObject , Now I want to convert it to JSONObject but my POJO contains an array which is not converted using below code:

Email Class:

```
package pojo;

public class Email {

String TYPE;
String VALUE;

public Email() {
}

public Email(String TYPE, String VALUE) {

    this.TYPE = TYPE;

    this.VALUE = VALUE;

}

public void setTYPE(String TYPE) {

    this.TYPE = TYPE;

}

public String getTYPE() {

    return this.TYPE;

}

public void setVALUE(String VALUE) {

    this.VALUE = VALUE;

}

public String getVALUE() {

    return this.VALUE;
}
```

}

PostAccountCreateAPI Class:

```
package pojo;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class PostAccountCreateAPI {

private String FirstName;
private String LastName;
private String PASSWORD;
private List<Email> Email;
static List<Email> emailList = new ArrayList<>();

public PostAccountCreateAPI() {
}


public void setFirstName(String FirstName) {

    this.FirstName = FirstName;

}

public String getFirstName() {

    return this.FirstName;

}

public void setLastName(String LastName) {

    this.LastName = LastName;

}

public String getLastName() {

    return this.LastName;

}

public void setPASSWORD(String PASSWORD) {

    this.PASSWORD = PASSWORD;

}

public String getPASSWORD() {

    return this.PASSWORD;

}

public void setEmail(List<Email> Email) {

    this.Email = Email;

}

public List<Email> getEmail() {

    return this.Email;

}
```

}

I have created the Object of PostAccountCreateAPI Class and converting to JSONString as below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();   
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(postAccountCreateAPI);
System.out.println(json);
```

But I am not getting Email as array, Below is the response I got:
`{"lastName":null,"email":null,"firstName":null,"password":null}`

I am expecting it in below format:

```
    "FirstName": "FSFBE",
    "LastName": "LoUSj",
    "PASSWORD": "p@$$word123",
    "Email": [
        {
            "TYPE": "Primary",
            "VALUE": "test7EZK0@mail7.io"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is something wrong with your `postAccountCreateAPI` initialization. Can you please copy the line, where you call the constructor and/or set the attributes?
Plus I think you should follow the java naming convention. You violate almost every rule.
https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions